# Catch exception from `await` while maintaining the await returns to the outer scope

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a nice linear code enabled by `async` `await`, which returns a value. Most of my code is along this pattern:

```cs
var a = await Foo1();
Bar1(a);
Bar2(a);
Bar3(a);

var b = await Foo2(a);
Bar4(a,b);
```

But then I need to catch the exception from the `async` function.

```cs
try
{
    var a = await Foo1();
}
catch(MyException me)
{
    throw me;
}

Bar1(a);
Bar2(a);
Bar3(a);
try
{
    var b = await Foo2(a);
}
catch(MyException2 me2)
{
    throw me2;
}
Bar4(a,b);
```

This scopes the variable inside `try` and it is now a compile error. If I want to maintain linear code, then the `try` has to cover too many lines which I think it is not a good practice? Now it creates an indented pyramid:

```cs
try
{
    var a = await Foo1();
    Bar1(a);
    Bar2(a);
    Bar3(a);
    try
    {
        var b = await Foo2(a);
        Bar4(a, b);
    }
    catch (MyException2 me2)
    {
        throw me2;
    }
}
catch (MyException me)
{
    throw me;
}
```

So to `try` only that line and maintain linear code, I need to move the declaration to be nothing at first then assign in the `try`, to maintain the variable on the outer scope.

```cs
A a;
try
{
    a = await Foo1();
}
catch (MyException me)
{
    throw me;
}

Bar1(a);
Bar2(a);
Bar3(a);
B b;
try
{
    b = await Foo2(a);
}
catch (MyException2 me2)
{
    throw me2;
}
Bar4(a, b);
```

Now it is kinda linear. I have to stop using `var` too because I can no longer infer from the `async` method. I feel like C# would have provided a more elegant solution that I am missing?

Comment: You obviously need to do something else than `throw me(2)`, because you could just as well leave that out and the same will happen (with a better stack trace). Please [edit] your question to show what you actually want to do there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like

```
public struct Result<TResult>
{
    public static Result<TResult> Ok(TResult data) => new Result<TResult>(data, true);
    public static Result<TResult> Error() => new Result<TResult>(default(TResult), false);

    private Result(TResult data, bool success)
    {
        Data = data;
        Success = success;
    }

    public bool Success { get; }
    public TResult Data { get; }
}

public static class TaskExt
{
    public static async Task<Result<T>> AwaitSafe<T, TException>(this Task<T> task, Action<TException> handle)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        var result = Result<T>.Error();
        try
        {
            result = Result<T>.Ok(await task);
        }
        catch (TException ex)
        {
            handle.Invoke(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 public async Task Exec()
    {
        var cli = new HttpClient();
        var result = await cli.GetStringAsync("https://google.com")
           .AwaitSafe((Exception ex) => throw ex);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            //good
        }
        else
        {
            //bad
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using the `AwaitSafe` how do you know if an exception occurred or not, to continue conditionally in different directions? The only way I see is to update a local variable inside the `handle`, which is awkward.

Comment: If you want to stop further execution - just `throw`. If you don't want to throw - you should use `default(T)` as a marker that something was wrong. If it's still not obvious you can use `MayBe` or `Result` monads https://mikhail.io/2016/01/monads-explained-in-csharp/

Comment: So if `default(T)` happens to be a valid return value, the alternative is to delve into the theory of monads?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What do you think about my updated answer?

Comment: Now it's better. This approach is maybe usable. :-)

Comment: Idea: you could get rid of the cumbersome `Action<TException>` handle, by adding an `Exception` property to the `Result` struct.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable (without setting it) before the `try`.

Also, about `catch me;`:

- If your entire `catch` block is *only* going to rethrow it, then the `catch` has no purpose - just don't catch it at all. But I'm guessing that you maybe just omitted that code.
- If you need to do something in the `catch` (like log the exception somewhere), and then rethrow it, use just `throw;`. That will rethrow the exception *without changing the stack trace* - and that is important!

  - If you use `throw me;`, the stack trace will show that the exception occurred at `throw me;`.
  - If you use just `throw;`, the stack trace will show that the exception happened on the line it actually did (`await Foo1();`, for example). That's Better™. There is more reading about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception).

Here is all of that advice put together:

```
object a; //use the actual type
try
{
    a = await Foo1();
}
catch(MyException me)
{
    //do something else (or else just don't catch)
    throw;
}
Bar1(a);
Bar2(a);
Bar3(a);

object b; //use the actual type
try
{
    b = await Foo2(a);
}
catch(MyException2 me2)
{
    //do something else (or else just don't catch)
    throw;
}
Bar4(a,b);
```

Comment: `If your entire catch block is only going to rethrow it, then the catch has no purpose - just don't catch it at all.` A pedantic argument would be the ability to put a breakpoint (this is similar to the difference between `var result = Foo(); return result;` and `return Foo();`, it's a matter of easy breaking) But I do agree for non-debug situations.

Comment: Well then the catch has a purpose :) But still, I just set the Visual Studio debug options to break on *all* exceptions (not just unhandled ones). That also helps find exceptions that might have been mistakenly swallowed that you would otherwise never see.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all code inside the `try` that needs the variable declared inside the `try`?

```
try
{
    var a = await Foo1();
    Bar1(a);
    Bar2(a);
    Bar3(a);
}
catch(MyException me)
{
    // Use `me` or log the event
    throw me;
}

try
{
    var b = await Foo2(a);
    Bar4(a,b);
}
catch(MyException2 me2)
{
    // Use `me2` or log the event
    throw me2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by [mtkachenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097943/catch-exception-from-await-while-maintaining-the-await-returns-to-the-outer-sc/58098069#58098069). The try-catch blocks can be avoided by using the [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) method to `await` safely the `Task`, and then querying its property [`IsFaulted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted) to determine if it's safe to access the task's `Result`.

```
//var a = await Foo1();
var task1 = await Task.WhenAny(Foo1());
if (task1.IsFaulted) return; // Or do something else
var a = task1.Result;

Bar1(a);
Bar2(a);
Bar3(a);

//var b = await Foo2(a);
var task2 = await Task.WhenAny(Foo2(a));
if (task2.IsFaulted) return; // Or do something else
var b = task2.Result;

Bar4(a, b);
```

If you think that using the `Task.WhenAny` for safe awaiting is against the purpose of this method, you could use instead the extension method below:

```
public static async Task<Task<T>> AwaitSafe<T>(this Task<T> source)
{
    try
    {
        await source.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch { }
    return source;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var task1 = await Foo1().AwaitSafe();
```